# coda slider 2.0 to have % widths for responsive

Tags: slider, liquid-layout

I have used Nail Doherty's coda slider for a few years now and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to make it responsive so that it uses % widths for the container not px. 
I understand that it needs a fixed width in the css to calculate the widths in the js for the panels to make the slider work/display correctly but wondered if there was a fix to make it liquid.

I can use media screen queries for it to re-size at certain screen resolutions but was after a liquid answer if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the guy maintaining the Coda Slider now since around July 2011. Because of the changing landscape toward responsive layouts, I created a new version of the Coda Slider rebranded as the Liquid Slider, grab it [here](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/).

It's easier to use than the Coda Slider, and I plan on keeping up with a tutorial series to teach beginners how to use it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin much appreciated, a really nice conversion of a great plug in.